# VsVim and visual mode in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsvim

when i select a text with `shift + arrows` or `shift + ctrl + arrows` (simple select a text..) then I have **visual mode** in vsVim. I'm anry and i can't delete text by `del`, but must to use `d` (to remove text). How can I disable visual mode when i'm push a `shift` on keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding the following to your ¨/_vsvimrc file:

`:vmap <Del> d`

(Another question is why you would want to use shift+arrows after having installed VsVim. I never use those key combinations when the more efficient Vim commands are available.)